# Where is 'emailauthor.jsp' is coming from?

Tags: javascript, email-template, custom-button

I've created a custom button sending email some time ago following these instructions:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtNyAAI

I just realized i do not understand where this script is stored from the JavaScript code:

'/email/author/emailauthor.jsp'

Where is coming from? There is probably very simple answer, but I cannot see it. Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL is nothing but a send email related to an activity.Go to any object that has Activity History in its related list (eg: case). You can see Log a call,Mail Merge, Send an Email. If you choose the Send an Email option you would be redirected to the URL (/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?) referenced in the article.

[image]
**Note:** some of the params like save=1 are now deprecated by salesforce. The article may not have accurate information and some of the suggestions may / may not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, to be picky, but I got redirected to the following: https://cs14.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=a02c000000EwCCX&retURL=%2Fa02c000000EwCCX . How does this become "'/email/author/emailauthor.jsp'" ? Oh, how do we know to use it? How the first person possibly figured it out from that URI?

Comment: It's a web page, like any other. Someone (several someone's, including myself) looked at the code and figured out how to manipulate the parameters. It's not a recommended practice though, because salesforce can and has changed the functionality of the parameters as time has gone on.